# Finding Value for Sine Squared of Weinberg-mixing angle

Tags: particle-physics, data

I am searching for an official value of $\sin^2\left(\theta_W\right)$ with an error estimate, where $\theta_W$ is the Weinberg-mixing angle. Since I didn't find this value in books, I searched on the following website: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/contents_tables.html

However, in the first two linked documents, I didn't find what I needed. 
Could somebody help please?

Comment: Such information is available right on the Wikipedia page for the Weinberg angle, with citations to the appropriate paper, of course the value will vary depending slightly on your experiment and scheme

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in PDG's [Physical constants](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2007/reviews/consrpp.pdf) as

> $\text{weak-mixing angle}\quad\sin^2\hat\theta (M_Z) \quad  0.23122(15)$

See also the footnote given there

> The corresponding $\sin^2\theta$ for the effective angle is $0.23152(14)$

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* have something broadly accepted, the CODATA 2018 [value](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?sin2th) 
is 
$$
\sin^2 \theta_W = 0.222 90(30)   ,
$$
but you must go deeply in *how* it is defined.

The PDG 2019 [review](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-standard-model.pdf), table 10.2 *should* leave you spooked about the precise definition, and the choice you must make depending on you application.